# Webpack jsx module loader fails when include given

Tags: webpack, babeljs, jsx, babel-loader

I boiled my problem down to a minimum test. I have an `App.js` file which contains a bit of jsx and which is to be compiled to `./bundle.js`:

```
// App.js
module.exports = () => <div/>
```

My webpack config seems quite standard with

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './App.js',
    output: {
        filename: './bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                //include: ['./includes'],  // <- Problem line
                query: {
                    plugins: [
                        ['transform-react-jsx']
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This works and compiles correctly only if the line with `include` is removed. If I enable that line then I get the error

```
Module parse failed: ./App.js Unexpected token (1:23)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| module.exports = () => <div/>
```

I have no idea why it would fail when I specify an include for the loader, even `include: []` fails with that same error.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include` is just like `test`.

- `include: []` means "include nothing"`
- `include: ["./include"]` means "only include files in the `include` directory"

so either if those will exclude `./App.js`.

Comment: Thank you, this absolutely makes sense. However, what would `include` look like? I get the same error even with `include: ['.', './App.js', './includes'],`

Comment: That would be because `App.js` is in `__dirname`. Why are you trying to add this in the first place?

Comment: I would have expected relative paths to work as well. I am working on making a client-only web app universal and am experimenting with this to inject client-only code in a clean way.